# Parallel functions return different results in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, primes

I have these codes in my windows form C# application:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 1000000); };
    thread1_thread = new Thread(starter);
    starter = delegate { thread_func(1000000, 2000000); };
    thread2_thread = new Thread(starter);
    starter = delegate { thread_func(2000000, 3000000); };
    thread3_thread = new Thread(starter);
    starter = delegate { thread_func(3000000, 4000000); };
    thread4_thread = new Thread(starter);

    thread1_thread.Start();
    thread2_thread.Start();
    thread3_thread.Start();
    thread4_thread.Start();

}

void thread_func(decimal input1,decimal input2)
{
    for (; input1 < input2; input1++)
    {
        threadNumbers_list.Add(input1);
        if (input1 % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (isPrime_func(input1))
            {
                PrimeNumbers_decimal_list.Add(input1);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static Boolean isPrime_func(decimal number)
    {
        decimal boundary = (decimal)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt((double)number));

        if (number == 1) return false;
        if (number == 2) return true;

        for (decimal i = 2; i <= boundary; ++i)
        {
            if (number % i == 0) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Every time I run click that button I get different results. I have tried many things but could not figure out why this happens. Even for lower ranges it happens. Just in range of 100 numbers for example it gives the same result always.
Some time my list count reaches 283138 and sometimes 283131 and other near numbers.

Another weird this is that when I comment checking even numbers, operation takes shorter time than this mode. What's wrong?

Comment: `threadNumbers_list` and `PrimeNumbers_decimal_list` are probably not thread safe.

Comment: i created that list just for checking if all iteration happens or not!

Comment: What about `PrimeNumbers_decimal_list`? Also, how do you wait for the threads to finish? Do you use `Thread.Join`?

Comment: I check the VS events and wait for all threads to exit and also check app cpu ussage then click another button that show primenumberlist count

Comment: I created multiple thread multiple primefunction but could not solve that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple threads access a list, that list have to be thread safe or otherwise you are going to have a lot of problems.

.NET provides some [thread-safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx) like the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Side note: Please consider using `Tasks` instead of threads. Also, the .NET framework [supports data parallelism via the `Parallel` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Consider using such class instead.

Regarding the performance when you don't check if the number is even, I tested this locally and I got the following numbers:

- It takes ~76 seconds when I don't check if the number is even.
- It takes ~66 seconds when I do check if the number is even.

So this does not match your measurements. It might be caused by the way you measure. I measure with a `Stopwatch` like this:

```
//...

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

thread1_thread.Start();
thread2_thread.Start();
thread3_thread.Start();
thread4_thread.Start();

thread1_thread.Join();
thread2_thread.Join();
thread3_thread.Join();
thread4_thread.Join();

long result = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

//...
```

By the way, here is something that you can do that might save some execution time for you:

Create a normal `List<T>` instance for each thread inside the `thread_func` method so that you don't have multi-threading issues. Then after the loop finishes, you can update the master list from the local list. Only updating the master list has to be thread safe. In this case I would prefer that the master list is a normal `List<T>` and that you use the `lock` keyword to synchronize access to it because you only need to update it 4 times (the number of threads).

Comment: What is the definition of `PrimeNumbers_decimal_list`? Is it a `List<T>`? You can change it to `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and use the [`Enqueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287262(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the `Add` method.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm gonna check it. 
List<decimal> PrimeNumbers_decimal_list = new List<decimal>();

Comment: Yeah! thank you so much @Yacoub the result problem has been solved :)

Comment: how about that weird thing why checking for even numbers does not speed operation, also slower it?

Comment: You are welcome. Does the even number slow issue happen even after you used the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class?

Comment: Can you show the `isPrime_func` method? How do you measure the time?

Comment: I didn't check it yet! i'm gonna check it

Comment: I added function to my post
i measure time with VS 2015 Diagnostics tools

Comment: checked it with 'ConcurrentQueue<T>' but no change at the speed result!

Comment: I'm just amateur in programming, so i don't know much about these tricks. does this affects on time? 
and i don't know why VS tools show that kind of time!
any way i changed the thread code and it takes about 20s shorter than previous mode
i just check odd numbers in other way

Comment: `void thread_func(decimal input1,decimal input2,int lastdigit)
        {

            for (; input1 < input2; input1++)
            {
                //threadNumbers_list.Add(input1);
                if (input1 % 10 == lastdigit)
                {
                    if (isPrime_func(input1))
                    {
                        PrimeNumbers_decimal_ConcurrentQueue.Enqueue(input1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: ` ThreadStart starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 2000000, 1); };
            thread1_thread = new Thread(starter);
            starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 2000000, 3); };
            thread2_thread = new Thread(starter);
            starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 2000000, 5); };
            thread3_thread = new Thread(starter);
            starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 2000000, 7); };
            thread4_thread = new Thread(starter);
            starter = delegate { thread_func(2, 2000000, 9); };
            thread5_thread = new Thread(starter);
`

Comment: @ACE, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i could make it faster by checking last digit. and my question is what you suggested, does it make it faster?

Comment: You mean using a local list for each thread? I guess yes. But you always have to measure to be sure.

Comment: yeah i meant that. OK thank for your suggested. really helped me very much with that info about list